# Cannot connect to a database created from LANDO "Access denied for user 'lamp'@'%' to database 'lando_test_cli'"

Tags: mysql, lamp, sequelpro, lando

i am having an issue while trying to connect a database that I created in LANDO. There is my list of databases in LANDO :

```
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| lamp               |
| lando_test_cli     |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sys                |
+--------------------+
```

I want to connect to the database called `lando_test_cli`, so I'm in Sequel Pro connecting with

```
host: 127.0.0.1
user: lamp
password: lamp
database: lando_test_cli
port: 3307
```

But I can't connect and it throws me this error :
**Access denied for user 'lamp'@'%' to database 'lando_test_cli'**

Here's my lando info :

```
[ { service: 'appserver',
    urls:
     [ 'https://localhost:32779',
       'http://localhost:32780',
       'http://my-lando-app.lndo.site/',
       'https://my-lando-app.lndo.site/' ],
    type: 'php',
    healthy: true,
    via: 'apache',
    webroot: '.',
    config: {},
    version: '7.3',
    meUser: 'www-data',
    hasCerts: true,
    hostnames: [ 'appserver.mylandoapp.internal' ] },
  { service: 'database',
    urls: [],
    type: 'mysql',
    healthy: true,
    internal_connection: { host: 'database', port: '3306' },
    external_connection: { host: '127.0.0.1', port: '3307' },
    healthcheck: 'bash -c "[ -f /bitnami/mysql/.mysql_initialized ]"',
    creds: { database: 'lamp', password: 'lamp', user: 'lamp' },
    config: {},
    version: '5.7',
    meUser: 'www-data',
    hasCerts: false,
    hostnames: [ 'database.mylandoapp.internal' ] } ]
```